# How can i hook the UIPasteboard in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uipasteboard

I want hook the propery string in UIPasteboard, when it changes, i will do somethings. the property defined as:

```
@property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) NSString *string
```

I use method swizzle replace `string` to `stringSwizzle`, `setString` to `setStringSwizzle` like follows:

```
- (void) setStringSwizzle:(NSString *) string {
    NSLog(@"setStringSwizzle: %@", string);
    [self setStringSwizzle:string];
}

- (NSString *) stringSwizzle {
    NSLog(@"stringSwizzle - %@", [self stringSwizzle]);
    return [self stringSwizzle];
}
```

When i use code as as follows， it will enter setStringSwizzle and output my log:

```
UIPasteboard *uiPasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
uiPasteboard.string = @"test1";
[uiPasteboard setString:@"test2"];
[uiPasteboard setValue:@"test3" forKey:@"string"];
```

However, when i do a copy action in UITextView, it will not output any `setStringSwizzle` log(but the method `stringSwizzle` will out put log).

So, it there any way to achieve my goal？

*-------------*

plus:
i use KVO to observing the vale `string` of UIPasteboard, and when i do copy action in UITextview, the observer will not response.

Comment: When do a copy action in UITextView, it will use [UIPasetboard setData:forPasteboardType:]

Answer (score 0):

To Copy :

```
 UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pb setString:[textView text]];
```

To Paste :

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    textView.text = [pb string];
```

Comment: thansk, but what i what is swizzle the method setString of the UIPasteboard

Comment: why do you want to swizzle?

Comment: i want do sth when string is changed